# Lotus Notes and c# SSO

Tags: c#, lotus-domino

I am trying to create a SSO from my ASP.NET application to the Lotus Notes server.

Once the user logged in to my server, can I create a token in Lotus notes and then do a SSO.

thanks
Bhanvani

Comment: Since you are talking about an ASP.NET application, I assume that you are talking about accessing a Lotus Domino server via HTTP calls, so I have removed the lotus-notes tag and replaced it with lotus-domino.  Please correct me if I am wrong, because the correct answer to your question depends on this.  I.e., Olivier BOISSIN's answer is steering you in the correct direction if you are talking about making HTTP calls to the Lotus Domino server, but if you are talking about making Notes API calls the answer will be very different.

Answer (score 3):

Typically a Domino server supports 4 modes of authentication: 
- BASIC
- session (Domino Session Id)
- LTPA (IBM SSO)
- SPNEGO (new from 8.5.1)

LTPA is typically the way to achieve SSO. There are Domino APIs to create it but you will certainly need the user password. On the other hand, you can consider build your own LTPA from scratch (algorithm of LTPA v1 is available).

Last but not least, you can set an IIS in front of your Domino server and use the Websphere plugin so that a trust is define between Domino and IIS, which will forward the windows account to Domino

https://infocenters.lotus.com/domino/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_SETTING_UP_DOMINO_FOR_MICROSOFT_IIS_5182_STEPS.html